# MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE is moving in circular direction

Tags: android

How to find if MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE in onTouch is has moved in a circular motion or not??
    please help

Answer (score 2):

Recognizing a circle only with MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE is too much work. There is a package that helps you in that issue: android.gesture.

Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/package-summary.html

You can also check the Gestures Builder sample app included in the samples directory of your SDK.

Lars Vogel has a nice tutorial in this topic: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html

Hope that helps.

Cheers